# Inserir registros de uma tabela em outra em MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com dificuldade de inserir dados de uma tabela em outra, por exemplo tenho a tabela orçamento que possui os itens, mas os ítens podem ser de diferentes fornecedores, e quando aprovado este orçamento o mesmo deve gerar as ordens de compras para os respectivos fornecedores, exemplo:

> Tabela orçamento

Supondo que `SELECT * FROM orcamento WHERE orcamento = 330;`, tenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Tabela ordem de compra

Gostaria de criar uma ordem de compra para cada fornecedor como na tabela abaixo, sendo desmembrado, da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de criar um ordem de compra com todos os ítens do fornecedor como no exemplo da tabela ordem de compra onde foi criado uma ordem com os ítens de Id 2 e 4 que correspondem ao mesmo fornecedor de código 55, gostaria de usar esta funcionalidade diretamente no banco informando apenas o id do orçamento.

Estou utilizando php com mysql, e não mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um `INSERT` junto com um `SELECT`.

Por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO ordem_compra (id, id_orcamento, fornecedor)
SELECT id, id_orcamento, id_fornecedor FROM orcamento WHERE orcamento = 330;
```

Comment: então o problema é que dessa forma preciso saber o id do fornecedor, vou informar o id do orçamento que possui diversos ítens e pode havar um ítem para cada fornecedor ou vários do mesmo fornecedor, e o id do fornecedor só saberei após fazer o select do orçamento.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Mas você não poderia alterar "fornecedor = 55" pelo id do orçamento e ai você teria todos os dados daquele orçamento no select.

Comment: Editei a pergunta estava confusa mesmo, peço desculpas.

Comment: @WMomesso Editei a resposta. Mas sugiro alterar as nomenclaturas, me parece que o id na tabela ordem_compra é o id do item e o id_oc que é o id da ordem de compra.

Comment: @DiegoSchidt tudo certo, fiz um inner join e funcionou perfeitamente.